# Choose a database for Angular 2 + Electron app

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, electron

I am looking for best database choose for the application. This application has built in Angular 2 and Electron framework. Now we have enhancement for offline support for this application.

So I spent some time to choose the most suitable database and here it's that I had explored.

- [WebSQL](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/): Now it's marked as deperecated.
- [SQLite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3): Unable to
  find support for Angular 2.
- [Pouchdb](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb) It's better to use with IndexDb but I don't have any strong reason to use
- [Pouchdb + Leveldb](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/wiki/Internal-LevelDB-Setup)

**Note: Database length would not increase more than 10 MB**

Would you please suggest anyone one of the database from the above that I listed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have used SQLite3. You can compile it with native dependencies during the build process, it is small, and it would work well for your use case of under 10mb. Just note to change the DB path outside of the userpath when creating the executable for distribution.

To your bullet point of not finding support with Angular 2, you might be misunderstanding Angular's role. Angular is a front end framework, which is not depending upon any DB. It creates a service call to a backend via an endpoint (in most cases) to get and display results.

In your case, if you have a backend server, you put this in the POST request to get data back from the DB. Otherwise, use [IPC](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-renderer/) and click events.